# How does affect using so many regex function in jmeter's throughput?

Tags: regex, function, jmeter-plugins, throughput

I have a question. How does affect using so many regex function in jmeter's throughput?
I'm using several regex because my requests uses many parameters. I use directly the regex function in the "value" column of each HTTP Request Sampler. Thanks

Comment: Could you post some code or elaborate more?

Comment: For example, I have a parameter named W0030PERSECNUM_0001 and put in its value as 
${__regexFunction(name="W0030PERSECNUM_0001" value="(.+?)",$1$,1,,,PERSECNUM,)}
The PC processor work a so little more for this function, but whats up if I use many regex functions (20 o more for example)? How affects in jmeter's throughput? I want to load with 300 VU or more per remote PC (10 PCs).
I know that may to use one regex element for catching all values but the regex expresions are huge!
Sorry, my english is bad :(
Thanks